# How to set sequence number of sub-elements in TSQL unsing same element as parent?

Tags: t-sql, while-loop, sql-server-2012

I need to set a sequence inside T-SQL when in the first column I have sequence marker (which is repeating) and use other column for ordering.

It is hard to explain so I try with example.

This is what I need:

```
|------------|-------------|----------------|
|  Group Col |  Order Col  | Desired Result |
|------------|-------------|----------------|
|      D     |      1      |      NULL      |
|      A     |      2      |        1       |
|      C     |      3      |        1       |
|      E     |      4      |        1       |
|      A     |      5      |        2       |
|      B     |      6      |        2       |
|      C     |      7      |        2       |
|      A     |      8      |        3       |
|      F     |      9      |        3       |
|      T     |     10      |        3       |
|      A     |     11      |        4       |
|      Y     |     12      |        4       |
|------------|-------------|----------------|
```

So my marker is **A** (each time I met **A** I must start new group inside my result). All rows before first **A** must be set to `NULL`.

I know that I can achieve that with loop but it would be slow solution and I need to update a lot of rows (may be sometimes several thousand).

Is there a way to achive this without loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window version of `COUNT` to get the desired result:

```
SELECT [Group Col], [Order Col],
       COUNT(CASE WHEN [Group Col] = 'A' THEN 1 END) 
       OVER 
       (ORDER BY [Order Col]) AS [Desired Result]
FROM mytable
```

If you need all rows before first A set to `NULL` then use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e132/2)

Comment: I just came up with a problem! What if I have **A** - **A** into 2 consequitive cells - in that case this logic will not work, @Giorgos Betsos.

Comment: @BogdanBogdanov Why is that? Result will be incremented by one for the second 'A'. According to the OP: *each time I met A I must start new group*.

Comment: So may be the error is mine. Let me check my code again.

Comment: I found my problem :(. I must do the same operation on sub-selection (I have 2 levels). The problem is that configuration contains only **A**. So I have table with **A** - **A** - **A** ... and so on. In that case I get **1, 2, 3, ...**. I suppose this is specific of window finction, @Giorgos Betsos.